# Why isn't this function working on a button click?

Tags: javascript, html, button, addeventlistener

No clue why this isn't working...

I'm trying to write a function triggered on the button click, but can't get any response on click, which makes no sense to me.

```js
function test() {
  document.getElementById("submitZip").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // event.preventDefault()
    // var url = 'https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom';
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // this line gets the zip code from the form entry
    var test = document.getElementById('hello'); // this line clears the form after the user submits

    this.innerText = "Loading..."; // this line changes the button text to loading
    console.log("TEST");
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <form class="input">
    <h1 class="title"> Find A Pet Near You! </h1>
    <label for="zip" id="hello">Zip</label>
    <input type="text" name="zip" id="zip">
    <button type="submit" id="submitZip" onclick="test()"> Submit </button>
  </form>
</body>
<script src='script.js'></script>

</html>
```

I'm just trying to detect any sign of life on the button click...

Comment: Your code sets up a call to `test()` in the HTML via an "onclick" attribute. Then, in the `test()` function, you get the same button element and add an event listener to it. Why? Why not just do the work in `test()`?  It's already bound to the "click" event.

Comment: For a `<button type="submit"`, on click, it will submit the associated form immediately, which will cause your browser to refresh. You have `event.preventDefault()`, but it is commented out. If you move the `console.log('TEST')` before `event.preventDefault()`, and uncomment that line, you should see `'TEST'` logged to your browser's console (F12 > Console tab), assuming everything else is setup correctly, which the comment above suggests it is not.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need an additional listener (`addEventListener`) inside the `test` function, since you've given `test` to be working on click for the button.

**Possible solution 1.**

In case your HTML code needs to stay same, your JS code needs to be:

```
function test() {
    // event.preventDefault()
    // var url = 'https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom';
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // this line gets the zip code from the form entry
    var test = document.getElementById('hello'); // this line clears the form after the user submits
    // this.innerText = "Loading..."; // this line changes the button text to loading

    console.log("TEST");
}
```

which will print the `TEST`.

**Possible solution 2.**

In case you delete `onclick` attribute from the HTML, your JS code can be:

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("submitZip").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
        // event.preventDefault()
        // var url = 'https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom';
        var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // this line gets the zip code from the form entry
        var test = document.getElementById('hello'); // this line clears the form after the user submits
        this.innerText = "Loading..."; // this line changes the button text to loading
        console.log("TEST");
    });
}

test();
```

or

```
document.getElementById("submitZip").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    // event.preventDefault()
    // var url = 'https://api.petfinder.com/pet.getRandom';
    var zip = document.getElementById('zip').value; // this line gets the zip code from the form entry
    var test = document.getElementById('hello'); // this line clears the form after the user submits
    this.innerText = "Loading..."; // this line changes the button text to loading
    console.log("TEST");
});
```

Note: I've left all your comments as you've written them.